# squid doesn't cache anything at all

Tags: proxy, squid, cache

I have configured squid for anonymous search and cache proxy. Initially it was working well, after two weeks it becomes slow(loading web page become slow) then again I had to looked into squid. I saw there was updated standard version of squid then I did update squid from 3.1.19 to 3.2.4. Now squid is running all the traffic from our network going through squid proxy server only. I see again internet connection is slow then I enabled cache feature in squid as

```
cache_dir ufs /var/cache/squid3 10240 32 512
cache_mem 256 MB
```

I checked the size of cache as

```
du -sh /var/cache/squid3
```

output:

> 65 M

I checked the size of cache again after one day I see same `65 M`, squid didn't cache anything at all. what would be the problem? should I configure anything else.

And the internet connection is very slow.

Comment: What other settings do you have?  There are many other squid options that directly modify the cachign behavior.  There are options about the cache object size, the maximum age, and so on.

Comment: @Zoredache I have uncommented only above mentioned two lines for cache option, remaining are commented as it is default.

Comment: I'd confirm that the users are using the proxy. tail -f access.log to see the activity.

Comment: @diegows I did tail -f /var/log/squid3/access.log, but I see no output

Comment: There is the answer, your users aren't using the proxy. :)

Comment: @diegows But I have diverted all traffic from mikrotik router to proxy server. The movement I divert all traffic to proxy server's 3128 port I can experience that internet become slow.

Comment: Something isn't work there. If you have a almost default configuration, access.log should log all the traffic. If traffic log doesn't move, there is no traffic. Your users are bypassing the proxy.

Comment: MT.. best to use the Proxy on the MT device too, then simply set squid as the parent proxy. Don't forget to bypass the MT proxy for the squid server, otherwise you'll get a loop.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that there is nothing in the `access.log` suggests that the requests from clients aren't being routed through Squid at all but something else on the same server.

Could you post more information about your setup, Squid config and what you actually have on the same box (censoring it first of course).